# Non equi join in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I wonder which is the appropriate or standard way to run a *non equi join* in pandas, like:

select a.date, min(b.date)
  from event a, event b
where a.date < b.date
group by a.date

Some workarounds in mind may be: 
1) cross join and then filter but unfeasible with 200,000 rows. 
2) coding a nested loop: iterate over *a* and search in *b* for each *a* row

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you showed a small example showing `a`, `b`, and the result you expect from the join.